# how to solve 1/x!(47-x)!=1

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

This problem is made by me.
But I don't know how to solve this factorial equation because it doesn't seem to be easy.

Can anyone please explain to me it's solution?

Comment: Is your left-hand side $\frac{(47-x)!}{x!}$ or $\frac{1}{x!(47-x)!}$? Clarify with an edit. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax guide.

Comment: Since x has to be an integer ,for the factorial to be defined , there exists no solution for x

Answer (score 1):

As J.G points there are two possible interpretations for your problem. If you are considering the factorial as a function of natural numbers instead of its analytic extension using the gamma functions both possibilities are unsolvable. The first one, $\frac{(47-x)!}{x!}=1$ requires the denominator and numerator to be equal, therefore x should be $\frac{47}{2}=1$, but x is an integer, so there is a contradiction. The second possibility, $\frac{1}{x!(47-x)!}=1$ also leads to a contradiction because for every integer x greater than 0 and less than 47 you have $x!(47-x)!>1$